# two logical java projects in one physical project

Tags: java, architecture

I have a project which will have 2 different parts - one part will send messages to rabbitMQ, other one will receive and process messages from rabbitMQ. Both parts uses the same common java classes. For example java class-wrapper which will be sent and received. I think I should create one java project on maven or gradle but build it in 2 different ways - for the first and the second parts. Or may be it`s better to split it to 2 projects, but how to share common java files?

**UPDATE:**

I have 2 projects: project A sends objects to rabbitMQ queue, project B receives objects from rabbitMQ queue, both A and B uses common classes, so those classes should be shared between A and B. Currently, I created one maven project which includes A and B as modules. And I can compile both of them the same time. So I don't have a mess with third (common java classes) project, and everything is in one place. So I just wanted to ask how to do it correctly and better. Should I separate it to 3 projects or leave as it is or do it somehow else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create 3 projects.

- A) one for sending
- B) one for receiving and processing
- C) one for common code

When you build, you will build A+C, and B+C separately.  This keeps everything decoupled from the common code.

The reason to keep the common code in a separate project as it acts as the intermediary that defines the API between the two.  Think of deploying on a large scale.  You may have separate developers for each of the three projects, so you may choose to version releases to clearly define when dependencies are.  If everything is in one project, everything needs to be changed immediately, but you may not want your "common code" developer messing with your sending code (eg. in order for everything to compile).  If the different builds are deployed on different machines, only the common code needs to be updated, and not all projects.  Having separated projects may take a bit of extra setup work, but will save you from numerous headaches in the future.

Unless you have a specific need to always deploy A+B+C together, 3 projects is the best design.  One example is making your own self-contained TX/RX protocol (eg. a walkie-talkie) where the client and server need to be co-located, and there is no central server.  But even in this case, to make it compatible with other applications using your protocol, breaking it up into 3 projects still makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Thank you, but why can't I use it all in one project? Is it a really bad design?

Comment: And how to debug it locally, use gradle dependencies then?